# How to add login with Facebook to a React Native App

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm new to react Native, I'm trying to add Facebook Login to my app. Can anyone suggest a good guide, updated for the latest version React Native.

So far I'm trying with 'react-native-fbsdk' which is not supported anymore, and I'm getting the following error:

```
./node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/lib/module/FBLoginButton.js:117:25
"export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  115 | };
  116 | 
> 117 | const RCTFBLoginButton = requireNativeComponent<any>('RCTFBLoginButton');
      |                         ^
  118 | 
  119 | module.exports = LoginButton;
  120 | 
./node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/lib/module/FBSendButton.js:61:24
"export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  59 | };
  60 | 
> 61 | const RCTFBSendButton = requireNativeComponent<any>('RCTFBSendButton');
     |                        ^
  62 | 
  63 | module.exports = SendButton;
  64 | 
./node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/lib/module/FBShareButton.js:62:25
"export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  60 | };
  61 | 
> 62 | const RCTFBShareButton = requireNativeComponent<any>('RCTFBShareButton');
     |                         ^
  63 | 
  64 | module.exports = ShareButton;
  65 |
```

My dependencies look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~43.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.5"
  }
```

and my App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data: any) => {
                    console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Expo and I had missed this https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/
Following those instructions it works for Android and IOS (I haven't tried myself) but it does not work for the web.